# useEffect hook unexpected behavior

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, addeventlistener

I'am actually trying to figure out the uncommon behavior of my useEffect hook.

the useEffect isn't matching the documentation explaining what is used to be giving as output.

here is my following component:

```
import tw from "twin.macro"
import { Logo, Navbar, HamburgerMenu } from "../components";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

const HeaderContainer = tw.div`
  flex
  flex-row
  justify-between
  items-center
  px-4 sm:px-12 md:px-14 lg:px-16 xl:px-20 2xl:px-24
  py-6
  bg-neutral-900
  text-zinc-100
`;

const Header = () => {

  const [isMobile, setIsMobile] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    const handleResize = () => {
      setIsMobile(window.innerWidth <= 768);
    };

    // Initial check and event listener
    handleResize();
    window.addEventListener("resize", handleResize);
    console.log("in the useEffect")
    // Cleanup
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("resize", handleResize);
      console.log("in the return of useEffect")
    };
  }, []);

    
  return (
    <HeaderContainer>   
      <Logo />
      
      { isMobile ? <HamburgerMenu/> : <Navbar/> }
    </HeaderContainer>
  )
}

export default Header


it is called it follows in the App component: 

import tw from "twin.macro"
import { Header,Hero,Footer } from "./containers";
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";

const AppContainer = tw.div`
`;

function App() {


  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <AppContainer>
        <Header />
        <Hero />
        <Footer />
      </AppContainer>
    </BrowserRouter>
  )
}

export default App
```

here is the output despite NEVER resizing the window object:

`in the useEffect Header.tsx:28:12`

`in the return of useEffect Header.tsx:32:14`

`in the useEffect Header.tsx:28:12`

as no variable resides as dependency array, the use effect should be run only once but the return statement is logging out in the return of useEffect which means it has been called more than what i were expecting, im i missing something ?

ps: the code i provided works fine as the mobile navigation is rendered when it should be, even though the console.log(isMobile) in the handleResize function is always outputting 'false'.

Comment: If you have StrictMode enabled, it'll run twice.

Comment: Docs for strict mode https://react.dev/reference/react/StrictMode .
In production strict mode will be disabled running only once.